# Determine the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The title says it all. Here the field of fractions of a ring $R$ is:
$$
Q=\Big\{\frac{a}{s}:a\in R, s\in R\setminus\{0\}\Big\}
$$

Comment: Do you have a candidate for this field of fractions?

Comment: You already wrote down the field of fractions (actually, there is an equivalence relation in there too). Does the question want you to down another ring which it is isomorphic to? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @JonathanDunay I could just fill in $a$ and $s$ but I'm pretty sure I'm asked to somehow "simplify" it, or write down what each element in $Q$ would look like.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried for that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ look like $a + b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So elements of the field of fractions look like $\frac{a + b\sqrt{2}}{c + d\sqrt{2}}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Can you rewrite that element so that the denominator is free of radicals?

Answer (score 1):

every element of $\Bbb Z [\sqrt2]$ is the form $a+b\sqrt2$, then every element in field of fraction is 
$$\frac{a+b\sqrt2}{c+d\sqrt2}=\frac{(a+b\sqrt2)(c-d\sqrt2)}{c^2-2d^2}=\frac{ac-2bd+(bc-ad)\sqrt2}{c^2-2d^2}=\frac{ac-2bd}{c^2-2d^2}+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2-2d^2}\sqrt2 $$

where $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Z$

it is an element of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$